# Magento 2: Get the qty of products before added to cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart, before-plugin

I'm trying to get the qty of products in a plugin with a method called **beforeAddProduct**, with this method I can manipulate things before being added to cart.

I need to check that the qty added to cart is 24 or 7, not less not more, in a Bundle product.

This is my code:

```
class Plugin
{
    protected $_attributeRepository;
    protected $logger;
    protected $cart;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    protected $quote;

    /**
     * Plugin constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        Logger $logger,
        AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,

    ) {
        $this->quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_attributeRepository = $attributeRepository; 
    }

    /**
     * beforeAddProduct
     *
     * @param      $subject
     * @param      $productInfo
     * @param null $requestInfo
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function beforeAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
    {

        $attributeSetRepository = $this->_attributeRepository->get($productInfo->getAttributeSetId());
        $attributeSetName = $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();

        if($attributeSetName == "7barrios-packs-personalizados"){

            $items = $this->quote->getAllItems();
            $totalProducts = 0;
            foreach($items as $item) {
                $this->logger->info("Name: ".$item->getName());
                $this->logger->info("Quantity: ".$item->getQty()); 
                $totalProducts += $item->getQty(); //THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO GET
             }

             if ($totalProducts < 24) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('Add 24 products from bundle!'));
            }
        }   

        return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];
    }
}
```

I only can get the qty of products when they are in cart, but nof before in this method, what can I do?

Can `$subject` or `$productInfo` give me the qty of products?

**UPDATE**

I'm still not able to get the qty products but found that the original method uses **getQtyRequest()** for getting qty.

I'm trying this, but I'm getting nothing, any ideas?

```
   public function beforeAddProduct(Cart $subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null){

       $product = $subject->getProduct();
        $request = $subject->getQtyRequest($product, $requestInfo);
        $this->logger->info("Product QTY REQUEST BEFORE: ".$result);


        return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];
    }
```

Greetings!

Comment: have a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574104/magento-checkout-cart-product-add-before-and-get-number-of-products-added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it would require some additional logic. See how the original method gets the requested quantity [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.5/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Cart.php#L373)

Btw, there is an easier way to get the requested quantity. You can create a before plugin on method [\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::addProduct](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.5/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote.php#L1609) and get the requested quantity in argument `$request`, see the sample code below:

QuotePlugin.php

```
namespace NameSpace\Module\Plugin;

class QuotePlugin
{

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function beforeAddProduct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $subject,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $request = null,
        $processMode = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType::PROCESS_MODE_FULL
    ) {

        if($request){
            $this->logger->info("BUNDLE PRODUCT QTY REQUEST BEFORE: " . $request->getData('qty'));
            $this->logger->info("BUNDLE OPTION REQUEST BEFORE: " . json_encode($request->getData('bundle_option')));
            $this->logger->info("BUNDLE OPTION QTY REQUEST BEFORE: " . json_encode($request->getData('bundle_option_qty')));
        }
        return [$product, $request, $processMode];
    }

}
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote" >
        <plugin name="before-add-to-cart" type="NameSpace\Module\Plugin\QuotePlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

See the testing video on my local instance [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GsrZMT1SJ8nGrugg4epKgAojrqd3mf_q/view)

Comment: Can you see my updated question please? I'm trying to get it from getQtyRequest() but not luck yet.

Comment: @OscarVazquez getQtyRequest is a private method, so you can't call $subject-> getQtyRequest(). Please review and implement it in your plugin.

Comment: how should I call the method ? $subject->_getQtyRequest() won't work either I guess, I think this method is the responsible for returning the qty, but don't know how to use it.

Comment: I've updated my response using the second approach.

Comment: Thanks Man! you saved my life, it works perfectly

Comment: Why the $product this seems to not be working when you add grouped products to the cart???